# Current constant circuit

Tags: kirchhoffs-laws

[image]

Did this circuit ok since no resistor on circuit? the voltage for each led is 3V for each led. Did i need to add resistor since 3Vx7=21V. The diode is led driver for 15mA. Btw, I'm designed for current constant circuit.

Comment: All components, including wire have some resistance somewhere.  We usually model it out separately as a separate ideal resistor for simplicity.  A constant current supply powered by constant voltage might increase its resistance to reduce current it outputs.

Comment: if the component marked 'diode' is in fact a 15 mA constant current source, then it's all good. It will adjust the voltage across itself to ensure that 15 mA is flowing, unless of course the LED voltages are a bit high and its voltage gets too close to zero, or even should be below zero. This is known as 'running out of compliance voltage on the current source'.

Comment: @Abel OK. Got it.

Comment: @Neil_UK Do you mean the diode will " adjust the voltage across itself" in this circuit in order to maintain 15mA current flow?

Comment: To be clear, a simple diode, such as a 1N4002 or 1N4148, is **not** a current limiting device.  By itself, it cannot "maintain" any specific current level.  If there is no other current limiter, such as a transistor circuit or even a single resistor, then the LEDs *are not protected* and could fail if the battery voltage is a bit high.

Comment: Your "diode" has to be something like this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant-current_diode

Comment: @AnalogKid OK. Got it. Thank you